# How can I sum contents of array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array called newresult which prints to the console like this:

```js
const newresult = [
  1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2,
  0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3,
  0, 0, 2
];

const sum = [newresult].reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

The array contents just printing as individual numbers.

Apologies, as I'm sure this is obvious, but what schoolboy error am I making here?

Also tried this:

```
const array1 = [newresult];
const initialValue = 0;
const sumWithInitial = array1.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue,
  initialValue,
);
```

Same result:

01,0,3,0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,2

Thank you

Comment: If `newResult` is already an array, why do you put it in an array?  Is that just a typo?

Comment: @David is right, `[newresult].reduce` is creating a new array and you're only reducing the new array.  When I tried to reproduce it, I automatically didn't add this extra wrapper.  My bad testing 

Comment: remove `[]` from around `newresult`. That is not giving you the behaviour you want

Comment: Thank you all for your input, many of the examples I've see show numbers in the array, so I automatically assumed that I need to show my array in here instead of the demonstration numbers, the proposed solutions have solved the problem. You are all very kind and I appreciate your time in helping out this novice. Warm regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting `newresult` which is an array by itself inside another array , So inside reduce callback it is basically converting the array to a string and adding 0 to it

```js
const newresult = [
  1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2,
  0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3,
  0, 0, 2
]


const sum = newresult.reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you brk, this is the answer. For any other fellow beginners, don't put square brackets around your array otherwise it does precisely what everyone has stated and nests it inside another array. I feel foolish, but problem solved. Thank you.